# Change starting value of barh chart, matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

On figure one you can see the chart I have: [image: Current Chart]

Here you can see the starting point of a chart is 0 but it has to be `-infinity`. so the chart always come form the right side. Its only like this when there are positive and negative values.

I have used the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rssi     = []
srn      = [-25,-30,-5]
freq     = []
sf       = []
messages = ['kitchen', 'garage', 'living room']


# plot
plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery')
plt.rcdefaults()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


y_pos = np.arange(len(messages))
performance = srn


ax.barh(y_pos, performance,  align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=messages)

ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('dBm')
ax.set_title('SRN')
ax.grid(axis = 'x',color='dimgray', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=0.75)
plt.show()
```

I have changed the values in figure 2 but that's how it should appear.

[image: Chart I wish to have]

Comment: Please could you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: How would you expect that to work?  If you have +5, -5, and +20, what common "zero point" would you expect them to use?

Comment: @TimRoberts that's the problem i don't know how set its "zero point".

Comment: That's not the question.  The question is, what zero point would you use?  Draw the graph on paper as you visualize it, with the axes, and post a photo.

Comment: @sbottingota sorry for not explaining it well, hope this helps. I have data that's going to be negative and positive, the default starting point is 0. But i want that the chart always start from the right hand side and not form default "zero point" 0. The highest SRN value is around 20, so if the bars have a staring point of 20 it short work fine for this value. Hope this helps.

Comment: @TimRoberts i should be 20

Comment: You might consider changing your data to "X-20" and set some custom tick labels.

Comment: @TimRoberts good idee, i have done it this way and it works